# AssertionError while using Scala 2.10-M3 reflection

Tags: reflection, scala-2.10

I am trying to invoke the method *typeOfInstance()* in the following (simplest) code:

```
import scala.reflect.mirror._

class Bar

object Main extends App {
  val bar = new Bar()
  typeOfInstance(bar)
}
```

but I am receiving an *AssertionError* while executing it:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: no symbol could be loaded from package annotation (scala equivalent is class com.hablapps.annotation.Bar) by name Bar
```

The above code runs fine in the REPL (with *:power* mode). The problem arises while running from SBT (with Scala 2.10-M3 set). Does anybody know what could be happening?

Comment: By the way, trying the same code in Eclipse raises *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Scala reflection not available on this platform.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with M3.

In that preview version of Scala, reflection only works with straightforward classloading schemes (e.g. when you run your application using good old `java -cp <classpath> <name of the main class>`). SBT is a bit more involved, and things blow up.

We've fixed this in 2.10.0-M4.